# Why can the chain rule be proven by showing that the set $M = \{ n \in \mathbb{Z}^+ : f(x_n) = f(a) \}$ is finite?

Tags: real-analysis, chain-rule

I am currently trying to understand this proof of Proposition 26 in my [lecture notes on the chain rule](https://www.dropbox.com/s/v7a05a0q71jhab7/chain%20rule%20proof%20part%201.pdf?dl=0).

In these notes, it says that proposition 26 can be proven by showing that the set $M = \{ n \in \mathbb{Z}^+ : f(x_n) = f(a) \}$ is finite. Can anyone please explain to me why this is the case?

Comment: The explanation is given right below proposition 26. What about this is unclear? If you don't state it in the question then don't expect answers different to what is already in the notes.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose that the set $M$ is infinite. Then there is a subsequence $(x_{n_k})$ of $(x_n)$ with

$f(x_{n_k})=f(a)$ for all $k$. Hence $f(x_{n_k})-f(a)=0$ for all $k$. Therefore

$f'(a) = \lim_{k \to \infty}\frac{f(x_{n_k})-f(a)}{x_{n_k}-a}=0$, a contradiction, since in Proposition 26 we have $f'(a) \ne 0$.